# How to concatenate two numbers into a Stack in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, stack, calculator

So I'd like to concatenate two numbers if true. For an instance if a user clicked on the button number "2" and button number "3" then it should be stored inside the Stack as ["23"] instead of ["2", "3"]. Whether it's 23 or only 2, whenever you click on a operator ("+", "-", "*", "/", "=") then you should click on 2nd number. It's for a calculator in Javascript.

**Example:**
User click on 23, +, 7 and then =. That should be stored as ["23", "+", "7", "="] in the stack, hope you get the point.

**UPDATED**

```
var stack = new Array();
for (let i = 0; i < length; i++)
                {
                    buttons[i].addEventListener("click", handle);
                }

        var prevop = '';

        function handle(event)
        { 
            const value = event.target.value;
            var myFirstInput =+ value;
```

I'm stuck around here.

```
            if(prevop == '+' || prevop == '-' || prevop == '*' ||prevop == '/')
            {
                var mySecondInput =+ value;
                var input = "" + myFirstInput + myFirstInput;
                stack.push(input);
            }

            if (prevop == '=') {
                document.getElementById("textfield").value = "";
            }

            prevop = value;

            switch(value)
            {   
                case "+":
                    console.log("+ was clicked");
                    document.getElementById("textfield").value += value;
                    break;
                case "-":
                    console.log("- was clicked");
                    document.getElementById("textfield").value += value;
                    break;
                case "*":
                    console.log("* was clicked");
                    document.getElementById("textfield").value += value;
                    break;
                case "/":
                    console.log("/ was clicked");
                    document.getElementById("textfield").value += value;
                    break;
                case "=":
                    var tmp = eval(document.getElementById("textfield").value);
                    document.getElementById("textfield").value += value + tmp;
                    break;
                default:
                    console.log("%s was clicked", value);
                    document.getElementById("textfield").value += value;
            }
        }
```

Comment: well throw some code here for us to tweak...

Comment: Where is your code, and at which point are you stuck?

Comment: @MKougiouris posted my code

Comment: @Stuart posted my code

Comment: Are you going to always just have 2 numbers (Eg.. 55 + 22, 3 + 4, etc..)? Or will you get into more complex things like 55 + 22 * 3 and do the calculations when the user pushes `=`?

Comment: Only two numers for now @Matt Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I implemented minimum "calculator" which will do stack manipulations as you described.

https://jsbin.com/maberic/5/edit?html,js,output

```js
window.onload = function() {
    var stack = [];
    var inputField = document.querySelector('#textfield');
    var buttons = [];
    var buttonsContainer = document.querySelector('#buttons');
    var actions = {
        'add': '+',
        'sub': '-',
        'mul': '*',
        'div': '/' // you can use custom symbols e.g. "÷" U+00F7 Division Sign Unicode Character
    };
    var buttonsHandler = function(event) {
        var button = event.target;
        var action = button.getAttribute('action');
        switch (action) {
            case 'input':
                var value = button.getAttribute('value');
                if (stack.length <= 0 || isNaN(parseInt(stack[stack.length - 1], 10))) {
                    // if empty stack or last is sign we can just push
                    stack.push(value)
                } else {
                    // else we need to concat last *number*
                    stack[stack.length - 1] += '' + value; // make sure we have a string
                }
                inputField.value += value;
                break;
            case 'action':
                var op = button.getAttribute('op');
                switch (op) {
                    case 'bs':
                        // implement here backspace logic
                        // e.g. remove last char from number or remove operator entirely
                        break;
                    case 'eq':
                        // implement here logic for "=" button
                        // avoid using eval: https://medium.com/mail-online/eval-is-evil-but-not-why-you-may-think-25961f9b01bb
                        break;
                    case 'cl':
                        stack = [];
                        inputField.value = '';
                        break;
                    default:
                        stack.push(actions[op]);
                        inputField.value += actions[op];
                        break;
                }
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
        // here you can apply "post" actions for your stack
    };
    /* Buttons "generator" */
    [ {type: 'input', value: 1 },
      {type: 'input', value: 2 },
      {type: 'input', value: 3 },
      {type: 'linebreak' },
      {type: 'input', value: 4 },
      {type: 'input', value: 5 },
      {type: 'input', value: 6 },
      {type: 'linebreak' },
      {type: 'input', value: 7 },
      {type: 'input', value: 8 },
      {type: 'input', value: 9 },
      {type: 'linebreak' },
      {type: 'dummy' },
      {type: 'input', value: 0 },
      {type: 'dummy' },
      {type: 'linebreak' },
      {type: 'action', sign: actions.add, action: 'add'},
      {type: 'action', sign: actions.sub, action: 'sub'},
      {type: 'linebreak' },
      {type: 'action', sign: actions.mul, action: 'mul'},
      {type: 'action', sign: actions.div, action: 'div'},
      {type: 'linebreak' },
      {type: 'action', sign: '=', action: 'eq'},
      {type: 'linebreak' },
      {type: 'action', sign: '< Backspace', action: 'bs'},
      {type: 'action', sign: 'Clear', action: 'cl'} ]
    .forEach(function(elem) {
        switch(elem.type) {
            case 'input':
                var button = document.createElement('button');
                button.innerText = elem.value.toString();
                button.setAttribute('action', 'input');
                button.setAttribute('value', elem.value);
                button.onclick = buttonsHandler;
                buttonsContainer.append(button);
                buttons.push(button);
                break;
            case 'dummy':
                var dummy = document.createElement('button');
                dummy.innerText = '_';
                buttonsContainer.append(dummy);
                break;
            case 'action':
                var action = document.createElement('button');
                action.innerText = elem.sign.toString();
                action.setAttribute('action', 'action');
                action.setAttribute('op', elem.action);
                action.onclick = buttonsHandler;
                buttonsContainer.append(action);
                buttons.push(button);
                break;
            case 'linebreak':
                var br = document.createElement('br');
                buttonsContainer.append(br);
                break;
            default:
                break;
      }
    });
    /* end */
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="description" content="Simple calc template">
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width"/>
    <title>Example</title>
</head>
<body>
    <input id="textfield" type="text" readonly="readonly"/>
    <br/>
    <div id="buttons"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Also, I would recommend you not to use eval: https://medium.com/@epoberezkin/eval-is-evil-but-not-why-you-may-think-25961f9b01bb

You can work with your stack. But you need to remember about multiplication, division, etc. about order of actions.

Comment: Your example actually worked. Could your explain me how the if statement is working, please.

Comment: Why remember it? He can ask a vague question about how concatenation and get a whole program built.

Comment: @Zagros sure. It consists of 2 parts: first one is checking `stack.length <= 0`, so if our stack is empty this statement is true, second one is checking whatever is last object in stack can be treated as a number in base of 10 (e.g. if you try to parse not a number ("+", "-", etc.) it will return NaN, so built-in function will say if it is NaN).

Comment: @Matt, without such example it was hard to me to explain algorithm, so I found my easiest way to show minimum prototype.

Comment: @Zekfad feel free to add the explaining part of how to concatenate and push to a stack.

Answer (score 1):

A bit difficult to answer without the code but as I understand your problem here is what I suggest:

As long as the + sign of your calculator has not clicked, you can concatenate your "strings numbers" with the + sign (NOT the + sign of your calculator).

Example for the first element of your array:

```
"2" + "3" // "23" when 2 and 3 are clicked
```

By doing that you can keep adding strings to the first element of your array.

Then when the + sign of your calculator or any other calculation sign is clicked, you add "+" (or the sign clicked) as a string in your array; at index 1.
With that the 2 first elements of your array would be `["23", "+"]`

You can have a logic that checks that the element at index 1 of your array does not match "+" or "-" or "*" or "/". If that has not been selected you can carry on adding numbers to the index 0.
Same thing for index 2 as long as at index 3 does not equal `=`.
That's what I understand you want to do. Does that make sense?

At the end of the day, if you want to return the result you can store everything as a string without worrying about making it an array (unless you want to have a trace of what was typed in separate elements). Here is what you can do to calculate the result:

```
function mathEval(mathString) { // this hack evaluates your math function and immediately returns a result.
  return new Function('return ' + mathString)();
}

console.log(mathEval("23+7")); // 30. You can trigger the eval when the = sign is clicked
```

Comment: So yeah I think we share the same thought dude. Basically just think of it as a normal calculator working. I just need to store the numbers in the Stack, whether I want 23, 3, 1, 55. It should be stored accordingly.

Because right now my problem is this.
When I want "23", "+", "55". I get it as "2", "3", "+", "5", "5" in the stack.

Comment: @Zagros I've also updated my reply in case the only thing that you really want is the result of the operation :) I thought that it could be useful.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't see your code contains anything related to pushing elements into a Stack? Am I missing something?

Comment: With the logic above you can decide when to push values to your stack array. You can do that by simply doing `stack.push` twice in your logic.
`var stack = [];` `stack.push("23", "+")` when a sign is pressed. Then `stack.push("7", "=")` when = is pressed. It gives you ["23", "+", "7", "="]

Answer (score 0):

You can check whether the keyvalue is numeric and based on this you can make a choice:

```
let fooArray = ["2", "3", "+", "7", "=" ]

function testFunction(keyVal) {
    let someArray = [];
    fooArray.forEach((f, i) => {
        if (i != 0) {
            let toBeInserted = fooArray[i - 1];
            if ( isNumeric(f) && isNumeric(toBeInserted)) {
                someArray.push(`${toBeInserted}${f}`);
            } else {
                someArray.push(f);
            }
        } else {
            someArray.push(f);
        }
    });

    return someArray;
}

function isNumeric(n) {
    return !isNaN(parseFloat(n)) && isFinite(n);
}

console.log(testFunction(fooArray));
```